# Woothemes Flexslider Problems changing slider speed

Tags: scroll, flexslider

I have been using woothemes flex slider and I need the automated scroll of the slides to be faster. In the jquery.flexslider.js file at the very bottom is the default settings, the only place in the file that I can find that appears to control the speed. However when I change the speed from 7000ms to a higher or lower number i get no change in speed at all, It seems like I am missing something really simple but i cannot work out which.

The flexslider is placed on a simple html page, the speed will not change on local version or online.

Ps im a new member and not allowed to post images yet and the code I pasted in this message displays in line and hard to read so I have left it out.

Has anyone come across this problem before and know how to rectify it? I appreciate any advice :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm working with Flexslider, here's code to adjust speed between slides:

```js
$(function(){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",slideshowSpeed: 3000,
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

[Here](http://www.webtechresources.com/2012/01/flexslider-jquery-slider-plugin/) a list of other options.

Answer (score 1):

Just use in code:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({ animationDuration: 6000 });
```

animationSpeed doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not your fault. Their documentation is wrong. Looking at the source code of the plugin on line 796 you see that they use "animationSpeed."

Example:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animationSpeed: 10000
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thankyou for your reply David I will check it later and post back :)

Comment: Sounds good. I've let woo themes know about it and they're working on updating their documentation.

Comment: Hello David

I have tried the example you gave, I cant get the speed to change though I may be doing it wrong.

I tried adding the exact example to the script tag at top of the html page but had no change to speed, I added the example to the jquery flexslider js file too but no change....  any tips?

ps my slider js file doesnt goto line 796 it goes to 565 and the jquery flexslider.min is all on one line

appreciate your help with this matter

Comment: Could you show me an example? We could talk about code all day long (I don't mind), but it'll probably go by a whole lot faster if I could take a look. Let me know.